# Edit each table row inside a foreach loop

Tags: php

I have a foreach  loop on a tale row. Each row has an "edit" button to edit that row only. Using JS, I want to get a hidden  open and edit the row.

Bellow is my code that I have tried but it works on one element only.

```php
<?php
foreach($sofas as $sofa)
    {

?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $sofa["name"];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $sofa["zirkar"];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $sofa["parche"];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $sofa["fiparche"];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $sofa["mizvasat"];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $sofa["asaly"];?></td>
        <td>
        <input onclick="myFunction()" type="button" value="ویرایش">
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display:none;" id="<?php echo $sofa["id"];?>">
            <td>
            This is my DIV element.
            </td>
        </tr>

<?php
    }
?>
<script>
function myFunction() {
<?php
foreach($sofas as $sofa)
    {

?>
  var x = document.getElementById("<?php echo $sofa["id"];?>");
<?php
    }
?>
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
```

I'm still learning, so please help me resolve my issue. I'm expecting the code to work on each individual table row.

Comment: How many IDs are there?  For each Sofa in Sofas, how many Sofas are there?

Comment: @Wookies-Will-Code About 40 and will be more later

Comment: CAN YOUR ID IS PASSED ON EVERY BUTTON OR NOT id="<?php echo $sofa["id"];?>  ?

Comment: @MohitKumar I haven't tried that. So you mean to give each button with an id? If yes then the JS function will get that ID as well making it not working

Comment: Not completely sure what your JavaScript is doing, but you shouldn’t need a loop inside the JavaScript. You should start by tagging elements so that JavaScript can access them in groups (via a class) or individually (unique ID). You can use sofa[‘id’] for this:  <td id=“<?= $sofa[“name”] ?>-<?= $sofa[“id”] ?>”> etc.  Now that JavaScript can access individual or groups of elements, you can then do stuff with them.

Comment: @TimMorton Do you mean to give each <td> an ID? I'm not quiet sure if I understand that!

Comment: Oh, my bad.  I was thinking row.  The idea being, mark each row as the same class, but with unique id.  Then have your javascript listening for an action (i.e., click) on that class.   You could take the information for that row and then submit to your database through ajax or whatever.  As it stands, your question is a bit too vague to really help:  you're not actually editing anything, just changing the display attribute.  The answer below makes a lot of sense with the information you've given us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use something like this:

```
   <?php
foreach($sofas as $sofa)
    {

?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $sofa["name"];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $sofa["zirkar"];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $sofa["parche"];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $sofa["fiparche"];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $sofa["mizvasat"];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $sofa["asaly"];?></td>
        <td>
        <input onclick="myFunction('<?php echo $sofa["id"];?>')" type="button" value="ویرایش">
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display:none;" id="<?php echo $sofa["id"];?>">
            <td>
            This is my DIV element.
            </td>
        </tr>

<?php
    }
?>


<script>
function myFunction(id) {
  var x = document.getElementById(id);
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
```

Code is very simple, you only need to send the element id to the js function.

Comment: sorry forgot about the quotes, `onclick="myFunction('<?php echo $sofa["id"];?>')" `, can you try it again ?

Comment: can you go to source code (right click->view page source) and send it to me ?